# Javascript assigning a method to an array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot assign the toUpperCase method to a specific value in an array (see below). I am a little confused because I thought objects were mutable and manipulated by reference? Maybe I am looking at it backwards?

```
var ary = ["hello", "there", "world"];
ary[0][0] = ary[0][0].toUpperCase();
console.log(ary[0][0]); // returns lowercase h
```

Any clarification would help me out a lot.

Comment: Simple, Strings are immutable.

Comment: `string` in javascript work like `Array`

Answer (score 1):

Since Strings are immutable in JavaScript, assigning a new character to an index of a String will not change the string at all. You need to create a new String like this

```
ary[0] = ary[0][0].toUpperCase() + ary[0].substr(1);
# H
```

We are creating a new string with the first letter capitalized and the rest of the string as it is.